# Error when setting up firebase messaging for background messages in kotlin flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

**My Application.kt contains:**

```
package com.example.somename
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}

override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
    io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
}
}
```

**The error I get when running it:**

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(22518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22518): Process: com.example.somename, PID: 22518
E/AndroidRuntime(22518): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.somename/com.example.somename.Application}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.somename.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.somename.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
E/AndroidRuntime(22518):
```

I have all my imports working fine and everything runs alright when i do not try to implement the background messages feature. The kotlin file is also being called correctly in my Manifest file.
I'm not sure of exactly what I'm doing wrong and any insight will be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Kindly register your service in a class that is inherited from Activity not Application.

Comment: Can you show in code, I'm not familiar with Kotlin